# DoxyWizard appearance: how to get everything bigger

Tags: doxygen, doxywizard, doxygen-wizard

How can I change the DoxyWizard appearance in order to have everything bigger?: bigger menu items, bigger text in the text window, etc.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there are no provisions for this. Only possibility would be to get the source code, find the appropriate places, change it and build.

Feel free to submit an issue in the doxygen issue tracker: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new